# How to merge two columns in a data frame in R?

Tags: r

This is a data frame.

```
df <- tribble(
 ~ID, ~AKT1,  ~AKT3, ~BRCA1, ~BRCA2,
  1800018, FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE,
  1800021, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
  1800026, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE,
  1800027, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
)
```

Here is the description and category of the colnames.

```
gene_to_pathway <- tribble(
  ~Gene,                   ~Pathway,
  "AKT1",                      "PI3K",
  "AKT3",                      "PI3K",
  "BRCA1",          "Genome Integrity",
  "BRCA2",          "Genome Integrity"
)
```

What I want is to merge the columns which belong to the same `pathway` as stated in `gene2pathway` above.

What I want to get is a final data frame like this.

```
> df2
PI3K  Genome Integrity 
1800018  TRUE  FALSE 
1800021 FALSE  FALSE 
1800026 FALSE  TRUE  
1800027 FALSE  FALSE
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You talk about the "same pathway" as if it's common knowledge. While it is possible to *infer* what you might need here, it's a bit vague as stated. Can you please add some additional information describing the stepwise logic?

Comment: @r2evans It is indicated in the second table. But there seems to be an issue on how to merge them.

Comment: Does row 1 of one frame correspond to row 1 of the other?

Comment: @r2evans Yes. The rows in df are the same as the ones in df2. I want to merge the columns of the same pathway and keep the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>% left_join(gene2pathaway, by = c("name" = "Gene")) %>%
  group_by(ID, Pathway) %>% 
  summarise(value = as.logical(sum(value))) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Pathway, values_from = value)

       ID `Genome Integrity` PI3K 
    <int> <lgl>              <lgl>
1 1800018 FALSE              TRUE 
2 1800021 FALSE              FALSE
3 1800026 TRUE               FALSE
4 1800027 FALSE              FALSE
```

Or you can write the function in `pivot_wider` directly thus saving two steps

```
df %>% pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  left_join(gene2pathaway, by = c("name" = "Gene")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, names_from = Pathway, values_from = value, values_fn = function(x) as.logical(sum(x))) %>%
  column_to_rownames("ID")

         PI3K Genome Integrity
1800018  TRUE            FALSE
1800021 FALSE            FALSE
1800026 FALSE             TRUE
1800027 FALSE            FALSE
```

dputs used

```
df <- read.table(text = " ID   AKT1  AKT3 BRCA1 BRCA2
 1  1800018 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 2  1800021 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 3  1800026 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 4  1800027 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE", header = T)

gene2pathaway <- read.table(text = "        Gene           Pathway
      1      AKT1                      PI3K
      2      AKT3                      PI3K
      3     BRCA1          'Genome Integrity'
      4     BRCA2          'Genome Integrity'", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks. In df, the 1800018 and so on are rownames. Does the code need a slight change?

Comment: Well done, I really enjoyed it. I have never used `value_fn` in my pivots. It seems to provide an interesting solution.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR, yes actually, if more than one value occurs per row in pivot_wider, it collects them in  a list and when a fn is provided it executes that function